# port forwarding by iptables failed

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, port-forwarding

I hope to forward from 192.168.1.230:9090 to 192.168.1.231:8080. I execute the following command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.230 -p tcp --dport 9090 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.231:8080
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.1.231 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.230:9090
```

It is very strange that sometimes it works by open url http://192.168.1.230:9090/ in browser, but fails for most times.

Do I miss something?

Comment: That is a very odd pair of iptables rules.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: try analysing packets on both servers by using  tcpdump -A 'tcp  port 8080' and    tcpdump -A 'tcp  port 9090'. check if you are receiving the packets correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The first rule seems correct. The problem seems to be with the second rule. 
When the packet returns from 192.168.1.231:8080, you want to check that the 
sport is 8080 (not the dport). 
You may want to use 
iptables -t nat -nvL PREROUTING
and
iptables -t nat -nvL POSTROUTING
And check the packet counters in order to undersand what goes through each rule.

Answer (score 0):

> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.230 -p tcp --dport 9090 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.231:8080
>   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.1.231 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.230:9090

I believe you misunderstand the use of the POSTROUTING chain.  It is not the "return" path.  Postrouting is simply executed after the routing decisions on your node.  The PREROUTING rule is designed to change the destination IP address and the POSTROUTING rule is designed to change the source.  It is unrelated to whether the packet is a return or not.  So in your example, the POSTROUTING command should be:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.1.230 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE`

in place of -j MASQUERADE, if you know your proxy node's IP you could use:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.1.230 -p tcp -j SNAT --to-source xx.xxx.xx.xx`

where xx.xxx.xx.xx is the ip address of the proxy